# Why won't AdvancedNewFile plugin show me the folder structure in sidebar?

Tags: sublimetext2

I installed the plugin, but when I save a file within a folder like `css/style.css` it won't appear in its folder structure in the sidebar.

Also, how do I set the 'global' folder location for this project? Or how to change to another project for later?

Maybe I'm missing something the tutor on tuts+ used, so any tips on additional plugins to help with these tasks will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll work to address your questions here, but I recommend creating an issue, if there really is one, on the [GitHub Page](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile) (I'm also the current maintainer of the plugin and I would probably respond faster to issues on the page because I also get email notification from those).

With that out of the way, I'll start on the questions. After you create the file, can you verify it is created?That is, after you create it through the plugin, can you see the file exists outside of Sublime Text? If so, can you give me more information about your setup so I can try to recreate the issue? Note it may also be a bug within the editor itself, but for now let's assume it's not. When you are creating the file, there should be an absolute path in the status bar below the input window. It should say something along the lines of `Creating  file at ...`

There are a number of configurations for you to manage, if you so choose. Details about these can be read about [here](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile#settings). These can be setup as global preferences (navigate to `Preferences -> Package Settings -> AdvancedNewFile -> Settings - User`). This will create a file for you to place your settings. You may look at the README or the default settings to see a list of valid keys. You may also setup project specific settings, which are explained [here](https://github.com/skuroda/Sublime-AdvancedNewFile#project-specific-settings).

The AdvancedNewFile plugin works, by default, by using the folders in the window it was activated. So by opening a new project/window, you will have a new set of top level folders when creating files. If you did not have any folders open, it will fall back to the home directory.

Let me know if I can clarify anything. I'll try to check back here, but again, creating an issue for any problems would be fastest way to notify me.